# Use grep in R dataframe column for a pattern matching and based on pattern need to convert other column values

Tags: r

I am new to R 
I have a dataframe like this

```
   Col1                     Col2    col3    col4    col4    col5
    city:Dallas             #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
    region:richardson       #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
    1.A.school1             0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0    0.0
    1.B.school2             0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0    0.1
    1.C.school3              n.a    n.a      0.0     n.a    n.a
    4.B.school5              0.0    n.a      0.0     0.0    0.0
    6.A.uni7                 n.a    n.a      0.0     0.0    n.a
    4.D.uni9                 n.a    0.0      0.0     0.0    0.0
    8.A.uni1                 n.a    n.a      0.0     0.0    0.0
    8.b.8                    0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0    n.a
    8.c.univ6                0.6    0.1      0.0     0.0    0.0
```

I need to find matching pattern from col1 and convert all the values of col2,col3,col4,col5 multiplied with 1000

for example : 
I need to find pattern 8.c.univ6 from col1 and convert 0.6. 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 * 1000

like wise i need to find more patterns and convert all the values

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way to achieve your goal. First of all, I do not know what class each column has. So, I assumed that all columns are in character. Given this, I wrote the following code. Your data is called `mydf` here. I replaced `n.a` and `#N/A` with `NA` and changed the class of Col2:Col6 to numeric. Then, I worked with each row using `rowwise()`. For each row, if Col1 has `8.c.univ6`, use `. * 1000`. `.` represents a column. Here . can be each of Col2:Col6. So I am multiplying each of the columns with 1000 as long as the condition is TRUE.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>%
mutate_at(vars(-Col1),
          funs(as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "n.a|#N/A", replacement = NA, x = .)))) %>%
rowwise %>%
mutate_at(vars(-Col1),
          funs(if(Col1 == "8.c.univ6") {. * 1000} else{.}))
```

EDIT

In the second `mutate_at()`, you can use `if_else()`.

```
mydf %>%
mutate_at(vars(-Col1),
          funs(as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "n.a|#N/A", replacement = NA, x = .)))) %>%
rowwise %>%
mutate_at(vars(-Col1),
          funs(if_else(Col1 == "8.c.univ6", . * 1000, .)))


#                Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6
#               <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1        city:Dallas    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#2  region:richardson    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#3        1.A.school1     0     0     0     0   0.0
#4        1.B.school2     0     0     0     0   0.1
#5        1.C.school3    NA    NA     0    NA    NA
#6        4.B.school5     0    NA     0     0   0.0
#7           6.A.uni7    NA    NA     0     0    NA
#8           4.D.uni9    NA     0     0     0   0.0
#9           8.A.uni1    NA    NA     0     0   0.0
#10             8.b.8     0     0     0     0    NA
#11         8.c.univ6   600   100     0     0   0.0
```

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(Col1 = c("city:Dallas", "region:richardson", "1.A.school1", 
"1.B.school2", "1.C.school3", "4.B.school5", "6.A.uni7", "4.D.uni9", 
"8.A.uni1", "8.b.8", "8.c.univ6"), Col2 = c("#N/A", "#N/A", "0.0", 
"0.0", "n.a", "0.0", "n.a", "n.a", "n.a", "0.0", "0.6"), Col3 = c("#N/A", 
"#N/A", "0.0", "0.0", "n.a", "n.a", "n.a", "0.0", "n.a", "0.0", 
"0.1"), Col4 = c("#N/A", "#N/A", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0"), Col5 = c("#N/A", "#N/A", 
"0.0", "0.0", "n.a", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0"
), Col6 = c("#N/A", "#N/A", "0.0", "0.1", "n.a", "0.0", "n.a", 
"0.0", "0.0", "n.a", "0.0")), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", 
"Col4", "Col5", "Col6"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can specify the` "N/A/n.a" etc in `na.strings` while reading the dataset

Comment: @akrun Thanks for that. I did not realize the parameter.  I used the parameter, but I am still struggling to import the original data. Do I need to use other parameters?

Comment: I was just commenting that you can include that point as a description.  Here, we cannot do anything else

Comment: @akrun Do you mean that adding this `na.strings` use for data import will help the OP? If so, I will add this point above.

Comment: I meant that this step could be avoided `funs(as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "n.a|#N/A", replacement = NA, x = .))))`  if it was already NA.

Comment: @akrun Ah got it. :)